# How do you create a virtual directory in Mac Snow Leopard?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualdirectories

I am using the server admin tool for the web and see where I can create sites with the +.  I thought that was creating virtual directory but it doesn't seem to be.  I need a site that uses port 80 but is like http://myserver/myvirtual instead of http://myserver which is what this one with the + does.

how do I make a virtual directory with the tool like in IIS?

Thank you.

edit:  how can I put a bounty on this?

Comment: What is "the server admin tool for the web"? I can think of several webbased Apache configuration tools.

Comment: Are talking about adding a virtual directory that is outside of the website's folder?

Answer (score 1):

I've no idea what tool you are talking about, but you can create a new config file:

```
/etc/apache2/other/myConfigFile.conf
```

And add [an alias directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html):

```
alias /myvirtual /Users/bob/myvirtual
```

(Then restart the web server)